# build a post data structure from form with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

I have a form:

```
    <div class="form_style">
<input name="name" type="text" id="Name" class="input username" placeholder="Username" />
<textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text"></textarea>
<input name="event_id" id="eventId" type="hidden" value="31"/>
<button id="FormSubmit">Add Comment</button>
<img src="images/loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

I can post the content_txt with ajax to php, with data structure. How to build the data, with all the variables?

Heres the ajax code for the content txt:

```
ar myData = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure
```

so i just wish to pass the two input (name, and event_id, for testing yet.)

And i wish to insert all the data to an sql database.

everything is working,  but only for the content_txt textarea. Any idea how to add the other content to the `varmyData`?

Comment: `$.post('url', { content_text: $('#contentText').val() });`

Answer (score 0):

Post the data  as a JSON structure:

```
var myData = {
    content_text: $('#contentText').val(),
    name: $('#Name').val(),
    event_id: $('#eventId').val()
};

$.post('http://www.example.com', myData);
```

Comment: Now ii am using ajax to post the data toward a php:
`var myData = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST", 
url: "response.php", 
dataType:"text",
data:myData,`

how will the datatype change if u use JSON?

Comment: The `dataType` is the type of data you expect back from the server, so I think there's no need to change it. You might consider changing the `contentType`, but since the default there is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should be good to go.

Comment: cant get it to work unfortunately.

after posting thedata with js, i am trying to get the data with

`$usernameContent = $_POST['event_id'];
$eventidContent = $_POST['name'];`

i cant event echo the content of the variables. any idea what do i miss?

is there anyway to print out the content of the myData, because i think something wrong there....

Comment: still could not solve the issue. i tried with js array as well, but with no success:

`data = [];
            data[0] = $('#contentText').val();
            data[1] = $('#name').val();
            data[2] = $('#eventId').val();`

the php part is the following: 

`if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) {...}` 

but it runs to the else part:

`else
{
 //Output error
 header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error occurred, Could not process request!');
    exit();
}`

could you please recommend solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you collect whatever form element you have under .form_style

```
var data = {};
$(".form_style").find("input, textarea").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      if ($this.prop('name')) {
           data[$this.prop('name')] = $this.val();
      }          
});
```